# Интеграция значений из стороннего конфигурационного файла при компиляции

Tags: компиляция, rust, config

main.rs

```
const VAR &'static &str = // config data //
```

config.json

```
{
    "var": 1
}
```

Есть необходимость в получении значений из конфигурационного файла при компиляции.
Формат этого файла не  важен, важен сам принцип преобразования внешних данных в статические, упакованные в конечный исполняемый файл.

*Я пока плохо понимаю раст.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для считывания файла в строку при компиляции можно использовать макрос [include_str](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.include_str.html). Аналогичный макрос есть для массива байт [include_bytes](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.include_bytes.html).

Так же, для различных сценариев сборки, в cargo есть поддержка [Build Scripts](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/build-scripts.html).